# Image is overflowing when I rotated it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter and ran into this slight problem. So I've created a Card widget and placed an image in it. Originally the image was horizontal, so I rotated it to be vertical. However after doing so, the image overflowed out of my card. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3p99.png)

```
Card(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             children: <Widget>[
                  Text("My Boat"),
                  Transform.rotate(
                      angle: -.9,
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('images/boat.png',),
                          height: 140,
                       ),
                  )
              ],
     )),
```

Comment: can you put your attached please so that we can help and simple of your code aslo

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices 
first, remove its height

```
Card(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             children: <Widget>[
                  Text("My Boat"),
                  Transform.rotate(
                      angle: -.9,
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('images/boat.png',),

                       ),
                  )
              ],
     )),
```

second, you can wrap it in Expanded like

```
Card(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             children: <Widget>[
                  Text("My Boat"),
                  Expanded(
                   child:                  Transform.rotate(
                      angle: -.9,
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('images/boat.png',),

                       ),
                  )
                        )

              ],
     )),
```